# Pandas dropping rows with time values

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have df (multi index)

```
               x    y    z
cu-a  charge   3    1    5
cu-a  time         7:30
```

when I run:

```
df = df.groupby(level=1).mean()
```

I get:

```
         x    z
charge   3    5
time
```

column y has disappeared (I think because of the time value?)
What I would like is this df:

```
           x    y    z
  charge   3    1    5
```

I have tried:

```
df1 = df.drop('Time', level=1)
```

but still get the same result of column y disappearing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this trick:

```
In [202]: df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').groupby(level=1).mean()
Out[202]:
          x    y    z
charge  3.0  1.0  5.0
time    NaN  NaN  NaN
```

or

```
In [203]: df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').dropna(how='all').groupby(level=1).mean()
Out[203]:
          x    y    z
charge  3.0  1.0  5.0
```